# Can’t get to virtual terminal from login screen on MBP with 19.04

Tags: boot, 19.04, macbook, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 19.04 and I am getting a black screen when I log in since installing nvidia CUDA drivers (for my eGPU). I can’t get a virtual terminal up on the login screen with fn+ctrl+alt+F*. Any ideas of how to get a terminal up so I can uninstall them from here?

Comment: Can you try access GRUB?

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have GRUB installed. I am triple booting Ubuntu, Windows and OSX and just use the option my to select my partition on boot.

Comment: What is your boot manager? Maybe you can try AskDifferent.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but there _should_ be a way to get a terminal up from the login screen, right?

Comment: Yup, using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` for example (Any Function key from 1 to 6 should work) but that's on a regular keyboard.

Comment: on my macbook pro touchbar late 2016, I use an external keyboard and `fn+ctrl+alt+F2` opens the terminal in Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually couldn't get this to work, but my workaround was to boot into recovery mode and use the terminal there.